# Get menu item view Robotium

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, robotium

I know that I can get current views of a screen using getViews, I can then assert them or send appropriate commands.
But can I also get similar views for menu items? May be a list of views for the menu using robotium?

Thanks.

Comment: What menu are you talking about?  If they are Views or extend View, you can get them in Robotium.